# What does the "source is an admin image" mean?

Tags: wix

I read the WiX documentation [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html):

> *AdminImage* (`YesNoType`) - Set to 'yes' if the source is an admin image.

I don't understand "*the source is an admin image*" phrase. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This attribute corresponds to Bit 2 of the [word count summary property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372870.aspx). You won't typically set this directly. Instead it gets set for the cached .msi file created as part of an [administrative installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367541.aspx).